# State is being kept as undefined. Not rendering to Map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I have an application where if you click on the map you can place a marker. However, whenever it is clicked it is returning the first time as undefined. After that it's not placing markers. Why is this? Have I done something wrong with the state management?

```
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coordinate : {
        latitude: undefined,
        longitude: undefined
      }
    }
    this.handleMarkerPress = this.handleMarkerPress.bind(this);
  }


  handleMarkerPress = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      coordinate: {
        lat: this.event.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
        long: this.event.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
      }
    })
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  markerIsNull() {
    if (this.state.coordinate.longitude == null) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.coordinate} />;
    }
  }




  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
        style = {
          {
            flex: 1
          }
        }
        initialRegion = {
          {
            latitude: 42.974536,
            longitude: -82.406590,
            latitudeDelta: 0.00003,
            longitudeDelta: 0.00002,
          }
        }
        onPress={(event) => this.handleMarkerPress(event)}
        >
          { this.markerIsNull() }  

        </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `initialState` as

```
coordinate : {
        latitude: undefined,
        longitude: undefined
      }
```

and updating it as

```
coordinate: {
        lat: this.event.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
        long: this.event.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
      }
```

and also checking based on `initialState` keys, therefore it is always `undefined`

You can set it directly as `coordinate: event.nativeEvent.coordinate`